# Creating trigger query to run from VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, mariadb

I want to create a trigger in a MariaDB (mySQL) database from VBA (MS Access).

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `updSortBy` BEFORE INSERT ON `cdevices` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET @maxOrd = 0; 
SELECT MAX(sortBy) INTO @maxOrd FROM cdevices WHERE levelID= NEW.levelID; SET NEW.sortBy = IF (@maxOrd IS NULL, 0, @maxOrd) + 1; 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This works when I paste in phpMyAdmin but fails if run from VBA.

Here is the corresponding part in VBA. I use an ADODB connection which works with other statements:

```vb
.CommandText = "DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER `updSortBy` BEFORE INSERT ON `cdevices` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET @maxOrd = 0; SELECT MAX(sortBy) INTO @maxOrd FROM cdevices WHERE levelID= NEW.levelID; SET NEW.sortBy = IF (@maxOrd IS NULL, 0, @maxOrd) + 1; END $$ DELIMITER ;"

.Execute
```

I get a syntax error:

> Error no.: -2147217900
>
> Error message:
>
> [ma-3.1.5][10.1.40-MariaDB]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER 'updSortBy' BEFORE INSERT ON 'cdevices' FOR EACH ROW' at line 1

Comment: FYI, use AUTO_INCREMENT columns, not dodgy triggers. Or insert a timestamp on an index column and select ordered by this column.

Comment: I doubt that `ADODB.COMMAND.EXECUTE` may correctly execute `DELIMITER` which is command-line client command, not SQL statement.

Comment: danblack - Thank you for your suggestion but I need this "numbering" on a group of records in my table not for entire table, I already have an ID autonumbering field

Comment: Akina  - Thank you for your message, but I want to ask if the DELIMITER is a command-line command, why phpMyAdmin execute the statement without any error?  I will check an alternative solution without using DELIMITER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your trigger code to single-statement form:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `updSortBy` 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON `cdevices` 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.sortBy = COALESCE((SELECT MAX(sortBy) 
                           FROM cdevices 
                           WHERE levelID= NEW.levelID), 1);
```

Now it does not need in delimiter re-assign.

Comment: I will check this and I came back with the results. Thank You :)

Comment: You are right Akina,  when I run my SQL statement without DELIMITER  works fine.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `updSortBy` BEFORE INSERT ON `cdevices` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET @maxOrd = 0; SELECT MAX(sortBy) INTO @maxOrd FROM cdevices WHERE levelID= NEW.levelID; SET NEW.sortBy = IF (@maxOrd IS NULL, 0, @maxOrd) + 1; END

Comment: So I need the DELIMITER  command in phpMyadmin not in VBA, thank You Akina